# Redis Cluster monitoring

Tags: failover, monitoring, redis

In some limited testing with Redis Cluster I've identified the following conditions where a failed master would be unable to failover:

The obvious, all the slaves have failed

All of a master's slaves on the majority partition are out of sync with their master

A master and all of it's slaves are all in a minority partition

Used memory is greater than the "maxmemory" config (if keys don't expire)

We plan on monitoring for these types of conditions, so ops can intervene before a Redis cluster goes unhealthy.

What other points of failure does a Redis Cluster have?